# Force grab keyboard focus pygtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a created a new window using pygtk. I want the system to give it keyboard focus immediately. What I am doing works most of the time, but when a window already has focus my new window is ignored. Is there a way to force my window into keyboard focus? The code I am using to open the window is:

```
    self.window = gtk.Window()
    self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
    self.window.connect("key-press-event", self.keypress)
    self.window.connect("focus-out-event", self.cancel)
    self.window.connect("destroy", self.cancel)
    self.entry = gtk.Entry(200)
    button = gtk.Button("go")
    button.connect("clicked", self.command)
    box = gtk.HBox()
    box.add(self.entry)
    box.add(button)
    self.window.add(box)
    self.window.set_keep_above(True)
    self.window.show_all()
    self.window.window.focus()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window is not visible when the focus call is made. Try this:

```
def create_window(self):
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
    self.window.connect("key-press-event", self.keypress)
    self.window.connect("focus-out-event", self.cancel)
    self.window.connect("destroy", self.cancel)
    self.entry = gtk.Entry(200)
    button = gtk.Button("go")
    button.connect("clicked", self.command)
    box = gtk.HBox()
    box.add(self.entry)
    box.add(button)
    self.window.add(box)
    self.window.set_keep_above(True)
    self.window.show_all()
    gtk.idle_add(self.bring_to_front)

def bring_to_front(self):
    self.window.present()
```